# How to fix 'Missing an image filename' error while try to add watermark using s3 image in paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, aws-sdk, paperclip

When I'm trying to upload watermark on s3 image through paperclip then it will give error like `not authorised` and `missing an image filename` because I'm using dynamic watermark URL. It is also stored in s3

photo.rb

```
has_attached_file :image,
                  :processors => lambda {|attachment|
                    if attachment.class.apply_watermark
                      [:thumbnail,:watermark]
                    else
                      [:thumbnail]
                    end
                  },
                  :styles => lambda { |attachment|
                    {
                      :medium => {
                        :geometry => "259x259#",
                        :watermark_path => attachment.instance.class.watermark_thumb_url,
                        :position => "SouthEast",
                        :s3_protocol => :https
                      },
                      :thumb => {
                        :geometry => Proc.new { |instance| instance.resize },
                      },
                      :original => {
                        :geometry => '1200>',
                      },
                    }
                  }, default_url: "https://s3_bucket_name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/shared_photos/missing.png",
                  :s3_protocol => :https
```

lib/paperclip_processors/watermark.rb

```
  module Paperclip
    class Watermark < Processor
      # Handles watermarking of images that are uploaded.    
      attr_accessor :current_geometry, :target_geometry, :format, :whiny, :convert_options, :watermark_path, :overlay, :position

      def initialize file, options = {}, attachment = nil
         super
         geometry          = options[:geometry]
         @file             = file
         @crop             = geometry[-1,1] == '#'
         @target_geometry  = Geometry.parse geometry
         @current_geometry = Geometry.from_file @file
         @convert_options  = options[:convert_options]
         @whiny            = options[:whiny].nil? ? true : options[:whiny]
         @format           = options[:format]
         @watermark_path   = options[:watermark_path]
         @position         = options[:position].nil? ? "center" : options[:position]
         @overlay          = options[:overlay].nil? ? true : false
         @current_format   = File.extname(@file.path)
         @basename         = File.basename(@file.path, @current_format)
       end

       # Returns true if the +target_geometry+ is meant to crop.
        def crop?
          @crop
        end

        # Returns true if the image is meant to make use of additional convert options.
        def convert_options?
          not @convert_options.blank?
        end

        # Performs the conversion of the +file+ into a watermark. Returns the Tempfile
        # that contains the new image.
        def make
          dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format].compact.join("."))
          dst.binmode

          command = "convert"
          params = [fromfile]
          params += transformation_command
          params << tofile(dst)
          begin
            success = Paperclip.run(command, params.flatten.compact.collect{|e| "'#{e}'"}.join(" "))
          rescue PaperclipCommandLineError
            raise PaperclipError, "There was an error resizing and cropping #{@basename}" if @whiny
          end

          if watermark_path
            command = "composite"
            params = %W[-gravity #{@position} #{watermark_path} #{tofile(dst)}]

            params << tofile(dst)
            begin
              success = Paperclip.run(command, params.flatten.compact.collect{|e| "'#{e}'"}.join(" "))
            rescue PaperclipCommandLineError
              raise PaperclipError, "There was an error processing the watermark for #{@basename}" if @whiny
            end
          end

          dst
        end

        def fromfile
          File.expand_path(@file.path)
        end

        def tofile(destination)
          File.expand_path(destination.path)
        end

        def transformation_command
          scale, crop = @current_geometry.transformation_to(@target_geometry, crop?)
          trans = %W[-resize #{scale}]
          trans += %W[-crop #{crop} +repage] if crop
          trans << convert_options if convert_options?
          trans
        end
    end
  end
```

watermarks_controller.rb

```
def upload_watermark_on_dummy_image
  Photo.apply_watermark = true
  Photo.watermark_thumb_url = @watermark.photo.image.url(:thumb)
  current_resource_owner.photos.create(image: File.new("public/shared_photos/dummy-image.jpg"))
end
```

It is giving error when try to run below command in watermark processors

```
command = "composite"
params = ["-gravity",
   "SouthEast",
   "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/s3_bucket_name/photos/images/000/000/025/thumb/download.png?1560325300",
   "/tmp/3151d071493084e42ac1e51947ef71ce20190612-25378-1usu3ji20190612-25378-135qwqy",
   "/tmp/3151d071493084e42ac1e51947ef71ce20190612-25378-1usu3ji20190612-25378-135qwqy"]

success = Paperclip.run(command, params.flatten.compact.collect{|e| "'#{e}'"}.join(" "))
```

It is giving below error:

```
Command :: composite '-gravity' 'SouthEast' 'https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/s3_bucket_name/photos/images/000/000/026/thumb/download.png?1560328681' '/tmp/703fb0e145df584135fc841239e8aa3020190612-27615-14xprt020190612-27615-10g8hgo' '/tmp/703fb0e145df584135fc841239e8aa3020190612-27615-14xprt020190612-27615-10g8hgo'
Cocaine::ExitStatusError: Command 'composite '-gravity' 'SouthEast' 'https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/s3_bucket_name/photos/images/000/000/026/thumb/download.png?1560328681' '/tmp/703fb0e145df584135fc841239e8aa3020190612-27615-14xprt020190612-27615-10g8hgo' '/tmp/703fb0e145df584135fc841239e8aa3020190612-27615-14xprt020190612-27615-10g8hgo'' returned 1. Expected 0
Here is the command output: STDOUT:
```